# Unable to launch chrome with selenium standalone

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to launch chrome using selenium standalone by using below command

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver-new.exe -jar selenium-server.jar standalone --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4444
```

However when I am triggering my webdriverio test for chrome, it momentarily opens chrome and the it crashes with below error

> {"traceId": "faca75a3db657eed4b96bdac93977746","eventTime": 1637343152240678600,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"driver.url": "http:\u002f\u002flocalhost:57786","exception.message": "Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created\nfrom tab crashed\n  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'\nSystem info: host: '', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created\nfrom tab crashed\n  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'\nSystem info: host: '', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:131)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:65)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply(SessionSlot.java:143)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession(LocalNode.java:315)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession(LocalDistributor.java:513)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession(LocalDistributor.java:440)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest(LocalDistributor.java:648)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1(LocalDistributor.java:612)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n","exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException","logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory","session.capabilities": "{"acceptInsecureCerts": true,"browserName": "chrome","goog:chromeOptions": {"args": [  "--disable-gpu"  ]  }  }\n"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding '--no-sandbox' in chrome options.